# ReactJS State not updating for passed props

Tags: reactjs

The following ReactJS code doesn't seem to work.  I am expecting the child component to take `error` as a prop and immediately assign it to the local errorState; howwever, the state never is updated.  Please consider:

```
import { useState } from "react"


const ApiMultiComboNew = (props) => {
    const { error,...nprops } = props;
    const [errorState, setErrorState] = useState(error)
    return <>
        <span>Passed error prop: {error}</span><br /><br />
        <span>Local Error State:  {errorState}</span>
    </>
}
const App = () => {
    const [formState,setFormState] = useState({})    
    const handleClick = (e) => {        
        setFormState(ps=>({...ps,recipients:"This Error Should Show Up"}))        
    }
    return (
        <div style={{width: "500px",height:"200px",border:'1px solid #000',padding:"8px",backgroundColor:"lightblue",margin:"0 auto"}}>
            <div>
                <ApiMultiComboNew error={formState.recipients || ""} />
            </div> 
            <button onClick={handleClick}>Press To Set The Error!</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

`errorState` Doesn't get assigned no matter how many times I click that little button.  Any help appreciated.

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/relaxed-cache-8stnsp?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A1%2C1-39%2C1)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue you're encountering in your ReactJS code is related to how state and props are managed in React, specifically with the **useState** hook.

In your **ApiMultiComboNew** component, you're initializing **errorState** with the error prop using the **useState** hook

This initialization happens only once when the component is first rendered. The **useState** hook does not automatically update the state when the prop changes. This is why errorState does not reflect subsequent changes to the error prop after the component is mounted.

To solve this issue, you need to synchronize the **errorState** with the **error** prop. One way to do this is by using the **useEffect** hook, which can observe changes in the **error** prop and update **errorState** accordingly:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const ApiMultiComboNew = (props) => {
    const { error } = props;
    const [errorState, setErrorState] = useState(error);

    useEffect(() => {
        setErrorState(error);
    }, [error]); // This effect runs whenever 'error' prop changes

    return (
        <>
            <span>Passed error prop: {error}</span><br /><br />
            <span>Local Error State: {errorState}</span>
        </>
    );
};
```

With this change, whenever the **error** prop changes, the **useEffect** hook will be triggered, and the **errorState** will be updated to reflect the new value of the error prop. This way, your child component's state will stay in sync with the prop passed from the parent component.

Also To specifically improve the performance of the **ApiMultiComboNew** component, the key is to minimize unnecessary re-renders and state updates. However, given the simplicity of your component, there's limited scope for significant performance improvements. But we can still apply:

Wrap your component with React.memo to prevent unnecessary re-renders when the props have not changed.

```
import React from 'react';

const ApiMultiComboNew = React.memo(({ error }) => {
    return (
        <>
            <span>Passed error prop: {error}</span><br /><br />
            <span>Local Error State: {error}</span>
        </>
    );
});
```

Comment: This smells very much like ChatGPT.

Answer (score 3):

The useState hook uses the variable you pass (in this case error prop) as an initialState, the argument is ignored after the initial render. So, the errorState will initial be "" in this case. No matter how many times the error prop changes, the hook will ignore it. If you want to update the error state everytime the prop changes you need to use the useEffect hook:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    setErrorState(error)  
 },[error])
```