# React Child component not remembering data it received from parent on refresh

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, parent-child, react-table, react-data-grid

I'm trying to pass data from a Parent component to a Child component that renders a table.  Everything works fine the first time, but if I push refresh, the Child no longer sees the data.  Any assistance with how to make the child see the data everytime is much appreciated.  Below is my code. Thanks:

```
const Parent = () => { 

    const [data, setData] = useState([])

    const getData = async(req, res)=>{
        try{
          const res = await axios.get(url to data);
          const data = await res.data
          setData(data) //<---this works fine
        }catch(error){
          console.log(error)
        }
      }

      useEffect(()=>{
        getData()
      },[])

    return(
      <div style={pageStyle}>
        <Child data={data}/> //<---this sends ok the first time
      </div>
    )

    }

export default Parent

Child Component:

    const child = (props) => {

    const [data, setData] = useState(props.data || []) //<--first time ok, no data after refresh

    const [fields, setFields] = useState([])

    const getheaders=(req, res)=>{
      let fieldList = []
      Object.keys(data[0]).map((field, index)=>(
        fieldList.push({field: field}) //<--This works the first time but breaks after because the there is no data
      ))
      setFields(fieldList)
    }

    useEffect(()=>{
      getheaders() //<--works fine on first load, not on refreshes because data is missing
    },[])


  return (
    <div className="ag-theme-quartz" style={{ height: "100%" }}>
        <AgGridReact rowData={data} columnDefs={fields} />
    </div>
  )
}

export default Child
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From React docs:

> Props are immutable—a term from computer science meaning
> “unchangeable”. When a component needs to change its props (for
> example, in response to a user interaction or new data), it will have
> to “ask” its parent component to pass it different props—a new object!
> Its old props will then be cast aside, and eventually the JavaScript
> engine will reclaim the memory taken by them.

You can ask the parent to pass down the new data props by putting props in the dependency array of useEffect like this:

```
useEffect(()=>{
  getheaders() 
},[props])
```

Comment: Thanks!  Makes sense.  The data now persists however, it would return 2x with a null set before actually showing the data which would break my dependent function where I try to get the headers from the data.  I got around this by simply adding a check to see if the data.length>0, then get the headers.

Comment: Your approach is right. React only runs useEffect after the initial render. It does that  to create the illusion that the loading is fast. Like here you need to fetch the data from the server which can slow down your app. And while your app fetches the data the client will see a blank screen waiting for the app to load. To overcome that React uses a concept called Hydration which allows the server to send initial data to client and then client runs JSX. Its like you see the button on screen but it won't work initially. As to why the 2 null sets it's coz components render twice in development

Answer (score 0):

The useState hook does not automatically update the state when the prop changes.
You can see my answer on below question:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/77672312/23012811

Comment: Thanks!  Makes sense.  The data now persists however, it would return 2x with a null set before actually showing the data which would break my dependent function where I try to get the headers from the data.  I got around this by simply adding a check to see if the data.length>0, then get the headers.